# How can I compile a C program inside the VS code terminal using MSYS2

Tags: c, terminal, compiler-errors, msys2

I am using a windows 10 laptop, I installed MSYS2 and it's components ( the gcc and gdb compiler and debugger) and included them in the %PATH% variable, now whenever I want to create a C file and compile it, a black kinda-like cmd prompt window pops up and starts loading endlessly and the vs code terminal keeps saying building program endlessly as well.

[This is the window that i get :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5PRT.png)
[And this is what i get when i run echo %PATH% on my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lTIU.png)

Note: I went on the VS code docs page (this one : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) and it helps and it worked perfectly the first time i run a c file, but when i restart my computer it rolls back to the weird prompt i get as i mentioned above